# Difference between "how", "the way" and "like" in the given sentences

Tags: word-difference

> I love you **how** you loved him.
>
> I love you **the (same) way** you loved him.
>
> I love you **like** you loved him.

In cases like this one, is "how" = "the same way"/"the way"/ "like"? Do all the sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: What dictionary definition are you working from? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/How conj. The manner or way in which: _forgot how it was done_.

Comment: [**how**](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=how) wouldn't be used as a conjunction in comparisons, as you can see in the definitions.

Comment: @user3169 Which is why I asked which dictionary definition they looked at.

Answer (score -1):

In My knowledge, three sentence are same meaning when we look over view of the meaning. But in depth we see means, It have difference.

1.First sentence looks the Quantity of love.
 2 Second one is looks way or handle or procedure of love.
 3.Third one represent your opinion.

But we looks of overall means both are same.

Comment: how <> quantity.  You are thinking of "how *much*".

Comment: What would you say are the differences between them three sentences? @TRomano